# Using Abstract in Multiple XSD Schemas

Tags: xml, xsd, abstract

I am trying to create a set of schemas, with the idea that there will be a core of standard schemas, then additional schemas will be imported with specific functions, and the whole lot can be described within a single XML document.

---

So, I have `SchemaRoot.xsd`, which contains the top level information for the document with an unbounded sequence referencing a Root Level Abstract Element called `SchemaRoot:Component`.

```
<xs:element name="Components">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" ref="Component"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
<xs:element name="Component" abstract="true">
    <xs:attribute name="ServiceID" type="xs:ID" use="required"/>
    <!-- I CAN PUT OTHER ATTRIBUTES/SEQUENCES HERE TOO, AND IT VALIDATES -->
</xs:element>
```

Now in `SpecialComponentSetA.xsd` I import `SchemaRoot.xsd`, and I create an Element called `SpecialComponentSetA:SpecialComponentA1` which is part of the substitution group `SchemaRoot:Component`.

```
<xs:element name="SpecialComponentA1" substitutionGroup="SchemaRoot:Component"/>
```

In my document, called `DeploymentSetAlpha.xml` which imports both these Schemas creates a Root level element, which contains a Component `SpecialComponentSetA:SpecialComponentA1`, and this validates fine.

```
<SchemaRoot:Components>
    <SpecialComponentSetA:SpecialComponentA1/>
</SchemaRoot:Components>
```

However, when I try to add any sequences, attributes, or anything more than the mere existence of the element in that substitution group:

```
<xs:element name="SpecialComponentA1" substitutionGroup="SchemaRoot:Component">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="AReallyImportantElement" type="xs:string"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

The scheme no longer validates, and I get `e-props-correct.4` error:

> The {type definition} of element 'SpecialComponentA1' is not validly derived from the {type definition} of the substitutionHead 'SchemaRoot:Component', or the {substitution group exclusions} property of 'SchemaRoot:Component' does not allow this derivation.

---

So, how can I get my schema to validate so that I can craft valid XML documents that contain structured data from various XSD schemas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, I feel silly for finding the solution this soon, however:

---

for `SchemaRoot.xsd`

```
<xs:element name="Components">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" ref="Component"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
<xs:element name="Component" type="Component" abstract="true"/>
<xs:complexType name="Component" abstract="true">
    <xs:attribute name="ServiceID" type="xs:ID" use="required"/>
</xs:complexType>
```

for `SpecialComponentSetA.xsd`

```
<xs:element name="SpecialComponentA1" substitutionGroup="SchemaRoot:Component">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:complexContent>
            <xs:extension base="SchemaRoot:Component">
                <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element name="AReallyImportantElement" type="xs:string"/>
                </xs:sequence>
            </xs:extension>
        </xs:complexContent>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

this then allows `DeploymentSetAlpha.xml` to validate

```
<SchemaRoot:Components>
    <SpecialComponentSetA:SpecialComponentA1>
        <AReallyImportantElement>FOOBAR</AReallyImportantElement>
    </SpecialComponentSetA:SpecialComponentA1>
</SchemaRoot:Components>
```